# How to Get Request Header values in Rest WebService

Tags: header, request

In my Rest Web Service, I need to get authentication data which are sent in Request Header.
I want to get those header values in my Rest Web Service. 
How can I get those Header Parameters from Request?

Comment: in a sense, this has a lot to do with the language and technology you are using. can you clarify that?

Comment: Hi Gabrial, It is Java. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Rest WebService, below should be the solution

```
public Response createpartnerprofile(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("Authorization")
String authHeader = httpHeaders.getRequestHeader("Authorization").get(0);
}
```